# Best process strategy for maintaining table access when dropping and re-creating tables

Tags: oracle, security, oracle12c

Is it possible to have permissions script all of the permissions in an Oracle 12c database without also simultaneously having the rights to modify either objects or data in the schema?

I  need the ability to be able to script the existing permissions on a table before a table is dropped and recreated in order to re-apply the permissions after the table is recreated. I will have to submit the scripts to a DBA to run and need to include these permisions when dropping and re-creating a table. If I cannot see the existing permissions, I cannot include them. The DBA will not allow me to have rights to do this myself

but he will only run scripts that I write 100% myself.

When I try to view the DDL for a table while logged in using an ID that does not match the schema name, I get the following error:

> To extract audit options, you must either have SELECT privilege on
>   DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS or log into the schema that you are extracting.

Will granting SELECT rights on DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS give me the ability to see all grants made on a table without also providing me additional rights to modify the schema or data?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a `DROP TABLE`/`CREATE TABLE`.  Use `DBMS_REDEFINITION` instead.  Here's a modified version of the sample code I keep around for this feature:

```
CREATE TABLE my_preexisting_table 
  ( a number,
    constraint my_preexisting_table_pk primary key (a) );

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON my_preexisting_table TO ont;

-- Start the online redefinition process...

-- First, check whether your table is a candidate for the process
BEGIN
DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE('apps','my_preexisting_table',
      DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);
END;
/

-- Create your new table with a new name.  This will eventually replace the pre-existing one
--DROP TABLE apps.my_preexisting_table_redef;

CREATE TABLE apps.my_preexisting_table_redef
(
  new_column1     NUMBER,
  a               NUMBER,
  new_column2     DATE,
  -- Let's change the primary key while we're at it
  -- Unfortunately, we have to rename our constraints because they share a global namespace 
  constraint my_preexisting_table_pk_r primary key (new_column1, a)  
)
-- Let's partition the table while we're at it...
PARTITION BY RANGE (new_column2)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL (1,'DAY')) ( partition my_preexisting_table_old values less than (to_date('01-JAN-2000','DD-MON-YYYY') ));
;


-- Takes long if your table is big.
BEGIN
DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE('apps', 'my_preexisting_table','my_preexisting_table_redef',
-- Map columns from the existing table to the new table here
       'a new_column1, a a, sysdate new_column2',
        dbms_redefinition.cons_use_rowid);
END;
/

DECLARE
num_errors PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS('apps', 'my_preexisting_table','my_preexisting_table_redef',
   DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_ORIG_PARAMS, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, num_errors);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Copy depenedent objects: num_errors = ' || num_errors);   
END;


-- Make sure there were no problems... or, if there were problems then they were expected.  For example,
-- there will be an error listed because it cannot copy the PK constraint from the original table (because we made a new one already)
-- and that's OK.
select * from         DBA_REDEFINITION_ERRORS where base_table_name = 'MY_PREEXISTING_TABLE';


BEGIN
DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE('apps', 'my_preexisting_table', 'my_preexisting_table_redef');
END;
/


-- Check out the results.
select * from my_preexisting_table;

-- Verify the grants are still in place...
select * from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where table_Name = 'MY_PREEXISTING_TABLE';

-- Drop our redef table when ready...
DROP TABLE apps.my_preexisting_table_redef;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't follow the procedure as given in Oracle documentation? [Redefining Tables Online](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#ADMIN01514)

Comment: No, there's no reason.  The answer I gave works, but if I deviated from best practice in a way that could cause practical issues, I'll be grateful for your comments.

Comment: By the way... the link you gave is pretty must what I did in my answer.  Also, I don't read it as a prescription for best-practices, but more of an end-to-end example of the process.  Was there something in particular you objected to?

Comment: Ok, I was confused by comment "**Redefine** your table online" followed by `DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE`. Actually you follow the process in documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  I made some minor edits that are hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function on the application schema that returns object privileges on tables owned by that schema, then grant yourself the privilege to execute that function.

That's the simplest solution to the problem.  Looking at the big picture, there are better methods but these might require significant changes to the process.

- User ALTER instead of DROP and CREATE.  There are a *lot* of dependent object types, it's impossible to think of them all.  For example, do the tables have any
  Virtual Private Database predicates, histograms built based on column usage, etc.  In an environment where the code "lives" on the database, DROPs are the enemy.
- Store the "one true version" of the database in version controlled text files.  This is the only way you can safely DROP tables and know exactly how to rebuild them.
  Only after the schemas have been dropped and recreated a few hundred times on local databases will your organization truly understand how things work.

---

Here's the easiest way to get this working:

**Sample Schema**

```
drop table test1;
create table test1(a number);
grant select on test1 to system;
grant references on test1 to system with grant option;
```

**Create Function to Generate Script**

Create this function on the application schema.

```
create or replace function get_table_grants(p_table_name in varchar2) return clob is
--Purpose: Return the object grants for a table.
    v_ddl clob;
begin
    --Enable the SQL terminator, ";" or "/".
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(
        dbms_metadata.session_transform,
        'SQLTERMINATOR',
        true);

    --Get the DDL.
    select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl(
        object_type => 'OBJECT_GRANT',
        base_object_name => upper(trim(p_table_name)),
        base_object_schema => user)
    into v_ddl
    from dual; 

    --Return the DDL.
    return v_ddl;
end get_table_grants;
/

--Grant access to yourself.
grant execute on get_table_grants to YOUR_USERNAME;
```

**Sample Output**

```
select get_table_grants('TEST1') from dual;

  GRANT REFERENCES ON "JHELLER"."TEST1" TO "SYSTEM" WITH GRANT OPTION;
  GRANT SELECT ON "JHELLER"."TEST1" TO "SYSTEM";
```